Как подключиться к MongoDB через TLS
У меня поднята база в докер контейнере:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    command: mongod --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem --tlsCAFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
      - ./certs/mongodb.pem:/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
      - ./certs/ca.pem:/etc/ssl/ca.pem
    networks:
      - patrebna-network

Как теперь подключиться?
 const user = process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME ?? '';
    const password = process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD ?? '';
    this.url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@mongodb:27017/patrebna?authSource=admin&tls=true`;
    void mongoose.connect(this.url);

    const connect = mongoose.connection;

    connect.on(
      'error',
      console.error.bind(console, 'Error connecting to MongoDB:'),
    );
    connect.once('open', () => {
      console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully!');
    });

